# CSS selector for only child, including text

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select `<b>` tags but only if that is the only content inside of a `<p>`. So for example, select the b in `<p><b>hello</b></p>` but not in `<p><b>hello</b> world</p>`. Is this possible? `:only-child` doesn't do it.

Comment: in order to do what?

Comment: AFAIK, CSS selectors don't know anything about text nodes, so I don't think this is possible without JS :(

Comment: As @AgusZubiaga said, this is not possible with just CSS. Why is this necessary? Could you use perhaps `span`s for the text nodes?

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors are clueless about text nodes.so, use span element for content like this:

```
<p>
  <b>hello</b><span>world</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>world</span><b>hello</b>
</p>
<p>
  <b>hello</b>
</p>


p b:only-child{
  color:red;
}
```

The "only-child" selector selects an element if it is the only child of its parent. The term "child" refers to elements that are not simply text.

For first "p" children are "b" and "span".

For second "p" children are "b" and "span".

For third "p" children is only "b"

only "b" of last "p" will be selected

```
<p>
  <b>hello</b>world ===> children is only b;
</p>
<p>
  world<b>hello</b> ===> children is only b;
</p>
<p>
  <b>hello</b> ===> children is only b;
</p>
```

all "b" elements will be selected

Answer (score -1):

You can simply find a common class for all  tags you want to change and insert it inside the element (< b class="">). In the CSS you can then edit the class according to your wishes.